# What IDE/ pragramming language to use for my android app?

Tags: android, google-apps

I read that there are different IDE and different programming languages one can use to make an android app, what makes it even harder to get started as a beginner. I am very thankful if someone can recommend what I can best use for my app.

My app will be very simple. Here are the functions I need:

- User can type in some number (how tall they are, for instance) and they will get an answer with an inage based on that value ("You are too small for your age" and an image of a small person or something like that)
- User can share the results
- save User input on a server
- User can buy items

That's it basically. Since the app is very simple and I am an absolute beginner I would be very happy if you can recommend what the easiest pragramming landuage to make that app is.

Comment: ... of course the app is not about how tall persons are. I modified my idea, so I can explain what functions are needed without telling the actual idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Studio for your development, which is free to [download](https://developer.android.com/studio).

Google has provided all the basic and most features as in Android Studio to start developing an app from scratch.

You will get blank templates to choose from and start instantly.

Android Studio provides the fastest tools for building apps on every type of Android device.

It has more features like:

- APK Analyzer
- Fast Emulator
- Intelligent Code Editor
- Flexible Build System
  and more...